# How to handle exception on handling exponent value with E trailing by no exponent value

Tags: java, exception, bigdecimal, exponent

this is my first question asked in this forum, so if question is novice please advice.

I receive the user input through `EditText`, hence it is a charsequence/string. then i created `BigDecimal` to hold that value. it handles exponents also gracefully without any trouble. but problem is when user enters values like `1.1E+` (without any trailing exponent value), code crashes in this piece of code. but it works when input is like this `1.1E+2`

```
EditText edit_text_left;
Editable editable_val_text;
....
editable_val_text = edit_text_left.getText();
BigDecimal val = new BigDecimal((editable_val_text.toString().trim())); // crash happens here
```

how to handle this?

More info: you can try this in google unit conversion app, by choosing Digital Storage : petabyte to bits conversion. and type 9 in petabyte it will show `8.106e+16` in bits section. now try editing `8.106e+16` to `8.106e+` and it will still work. i want similar handling only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to this community and all who replied. one of the hint gave me an idea to resolve the issue. there is no inbuilt method to handle that ending e/E/e-/E-/e+/E+. rather i made use of String.endsWith method to identify lonely e/E/e-/E-/e+/E+ and removed those from the string.

```
if ((str.endsWith("e")) || (str.endsWith("E")))    {
    str1 = str.copyValueOf(str.toCharArray(), 0, str.length() - 1);
}
else if ((str.endsWith("e+")) || (str.endsWith("E+")) || (str.endsWith("e-")) || (str.endsWith("E-")))    {
    str1 = str.copyValueOf(str.toCharArray(), 0, str.length() - 2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

IMO, what you should do is *catch* the exception (in an enclosing try-catch statement) and tell the user that they have supplied an invalid number.

If you want to handle a non-standard version of "scientific" format, you will probably need to implement your own number parser / converter.  You could do this by taking the standard parsing code from the BigDecimal class, and turning it into a static helper method that understands your non-standard format.

Alternatively, you could try to create regex that matches strings the non-standard form, and use that to correct the string to a form that is acceptable to `BigDecimal`.

But frankly, I wouldn't do that.  If the user is capable of understanding scientific format, they should also be capable of getting the syntax right ...

Comment: Really thanks for your quick response, but as I said an example of google app, I wish to handle this situation in software itself. like stripping off the E or converting exponent value into actual value through any method, like 1E2 to 100, then use 100 for computations... It will be great full if you could give me an answer for this.

Comment: @BaskarA - sorry, you will need to code it yourself.  (As I said, I think it is a bad idea ...)

Answer (score 0):

According to Javadoc for [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29)

> The exponent consists of the character 'e' ('\u0075') or 'E' ('\u0045') followed by one or more decimal digits. The value of the exponent must lie between `-Integer.MAX_VALUE` `(Integer.MIN_VALUE+1)` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, inclusive.

IMHO What you can do is remember the last entered exponent and then if exception occurs append last exponent if that kind of behaviour is required.